# how can i increase the space between the circles drawn for creating the snake in the snake game i am creating?

Tags: java, arraylist

I created a snake game on java and I managed to grow the snake whenever it eats food. But then the space of the ovals I draw are too close and I want to increase the space between them that should I do?

I tried changing the value where I add value to the ArrayList in the pts method.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener  {

//Create variables
Timer t;
static int x= 60;
static int y= 20;
static int score = 0;
boolean movexr;
boolean movexl;
boolean moveyd;
boolean moveyu;
boolean fa;
boolean lv1 = true,lv2= false;
static int rx= (int) (Math.random()*650+10);
static int ry= (int) (Math.random()*520+10);
Snake lvv1 = new Snake();

//end of variables//


public GUI() {
    initComponents();
    t = new Timer(30,this);
    t.start();
    lvv1.xs.add(x);
    lvv1.ys.add(y);



} 

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //all your drawing will go in here
    if(lv1==true) {
        lvl1(g);
        if(score >=10) {
            lv2=true;
        }
    }
    if(lv2==true) {
        lv1=false;
        lvl2(g);
    }
    lvv1.me(g);
    g.clearRect(x, y, 20, 20);


    ////end of your drawing
} 

public  void pts(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(rx, ry, 10, 10);
    if(lvv1.xs.get(0)<rx+10&&lvv1.ys.get(0)<ry+10&&rx<lvv1.xs.get(0)+20&&ry<lvv1.ys.get(0)+20) {
        rx= (int) (Math.random()*650+10);
        ry= (int) (Math.random()*520+10);
        score+=1;
        lvv1.xs.add((lvv1.xs.size()-1)+20);
        lvv1.ys.add((lvv1.ys.size()-1)+20);

    }
    for(int i=lvv1.xs.size()-1; i>0; i--) {
        lvv1.xs.set(i, lvv1.xs.get(i-1));
        lvv1.ys.set(i, lvv1.ys.get(i-1));
    }
}

public  void fail(Graphics g) {
    //g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(10, 10, 700, 550);
}

public void lvl1(Graphics g) {
    pts(g);
    if (lvv1.xs.get(0)>700) {
        lvv1.xs.set(0, -10);
    }
    if (lvv1.xs.get(0)<-10) {
        lvv1.xs.set(0,700);
    }
    if (lvv1.ys.get(0)>560) {
        lvv1.ys.set(0,-10);
    }
    if (lvv1.ys.get(0)<-10) {
        lvv1.ys.set(0,560);
    }
}

public void lvl2(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 700, 550);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 550);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 700, 10);
    g.fillRect(700, 0, 10, 560);
    g.fillRect(0, 550, 700, 10);
    pts(g);
    if(lvv1.xs.get(0)<=10||lvv1.xs.get(0)>=680||lvv1.ys.get(0)<=0||lvv1.ys.get(0)>530) {
        fa=true;
    }
    if(fa==true) {
        fail(g);
        movexl=false;
        moveyu=false;
        movexr=false;
        moveyd=false;
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (movexr == true) {
        lvv1.xs.set(0,lvv1.xs.get(0)+4);
        movexl=false;
    }
    if (moveyd== true) {
        lvv1.ys.set(0,lvv1.ys.get(0)+4);
        moveyu=false;
    }
    if(moveyu==true) {
        lvv1.ys.set(0,lvv1.ys.get(0)-4);
        moveyd=false;
    }
    if(movexl==true) {
        lvv1.xs.set(0,lvv1.xs.get(0)-4);
        movexr=false;
    }


    // x < x2 + w2 && y < y2 + h2 && x2 < x + w && y2 < y + h      //the rule

    repaint();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

System.out.println("keyPressed="+KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    int key=e.getKeyCode();
    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_A||key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        movexl=true;
        moveyu=false;
        moveyd=false;
    }
    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_W||key==KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        moveyu=true;
        movexl=false;
        movexr=false;

    }
    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_D||key==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        movexr=true;
        moveyu=false;
        moveyd=false;
    }
    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_S||key==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        moveyd=true;
        movexl=false;
        movexr=false;
    }
    if(key==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        //reset();
    }

}
public void reset() {
    y= 20;
    score = 0;
    movexr=false;
    movexl=false;
    moveyd=false;
    moveyu=false;
    fa=false;
    lv1 = true;
    lv2= false;
    rx= (int) (Math.random()*650+10);
    ry= (int) (Math.random()*520+10);
    lvv1=new Snake();
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}

private void initComponents() {
    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(

layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(

layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );

    }
}
```

When the snake grows the body ovals are overlapping each other i want the ovals to be close but not over lapping